# How to deselect a WinForm listbox with multi-value extended selection mode?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have read [this about deselecting a wpf listbox with extended selection mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947285/deselection-on-a-wpf-listbox-with-extended-selection-mode) and other questions posted so far.

All my listboxes, combox boxes in the Form is loaded via DataSource property using Enums at Form Initilization. Any of the controls that are on single selection, I can use the following property. But for multi-select, I can see nothing is selected but all the items are shown. I just want the multi-list boxes to be empty when form is initialized and opened up.

What built in property can be used to deselect a WinForm multi listbox with extended selection mode?

`lstSessions.SelectedIndex = -1` doesn't work obviously...

Comment: Do not understand the question completely but look up the List Box SetSelected Method `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.setselected(v=vs.110).aspx`. From the link `You can use this property to set the selection of items in a multiple-selection ListBox. To select an item in a single-selection ListBox, use the SelectedIndex property.`

Comment: Let me do few more shots. If still *spam* then need to figure out something else...