# Deselect on single click in a ListBox with Extended SelectionMode

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, selection

I have a `ListBox` with `SelectionMode="Extended"`. You can only deselect the last item by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> while clicking on it. I would like to be able to deselect the item by just clicking on it while not changing the behavior of the `Extended` selection mode other than that.

I only found [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947285/deselection-on-a-wpf-listbox-with-extended-selection-mode?noredirect=1&lq=1) about this topic and it actually has a different goal (being able to deselect all items by clicking outside of the `ListBox`).

Comment: So basically you want that clicking on a selected item should de-select it, right?

Comment: @mm8 yes exactly. If you think it was not clear enough in my question feel free to edit it. Unfortunately I sometimes feel what I write should be easy to understand by everyone while in reality it isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly you could handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event for the `ListBoxItem` container and de-select it if it's already selected:

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Extended">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="OnMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>3</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

---

```
private void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem lbi = sender as ListBoxItem;
    if (lbi != null)
    {
        if (lbi.IsSelected)
        {
            lbi.IsSelected = false;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This should allow you to be able to de-select an item without using the `CTRL` key.